# scale background image without div (on body)

Tags: background-image

Any way to do this without using a div?
Acting only on the body alone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a new property is css3 called background-size. This will do what you want to do but it isn't supported in all browsers yet

http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/

Comment: I was aware of css3, but am trying to get it to work with IE.